# How do you make strings "XML safe"?

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I am responding to an AJAX call by sending it an XML document through PHP echos.  In order to form this XML document, I loop through the records of a database.  The problem is that the database includes records that have '<' symbols in them.  So naturally, the browser throws an error at that particular spot.  How can this be fixed?

Comment: Did you try creating a function that will replace all sensible character by their xml equivalents. Or maybe include all value with potential character within "" ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

By either escaping those characters with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), or, perhaps more appropriately, using a library for building XML documents, such as [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument) or [XMLWriter](http://www.php.net/XMLWriter).

Another alternative would be to use CDATA sections, but then you'd have to look out for occurrences of `]]>`.

Take also into consideration that that you must respect the encoding you define for the XML document (by default UTF-8).

Comment: htmlspecialchars isn't the best way of doing it, because as the name suggests it's meant for HTML output, not XML.  It will, for example, convert < to &lt;, when for XML the correct encoding is &amp;lt;  DOMDocument, simpleXML or similar XML-aware extensions would be a better bet.

Comment: @Gordon Hum? Since when is `&lt;` not correct for XML? `htmlspecialchars` actually only does entity substitution with entities that are guaranteed to be available for *any* XML document, and even leaves one behind (replaces `'` with `&#039;` when it could use `&apos;`; of course, `&#039;` is correct too).

Comment: @Gordon By the way, there are *some* reasons why `htmlspecialchars` may be insufficient for XML (namely, it doesn't replace forbidden characters in XML and it doesn't encode forbidden entities when $double_encode is TRUE) -- which, btw, I have addressed by introducing profiles in trunk's version of htmlspecialchars/entities --, but what you say is simply not true. What you're describing is a double encoding, you need `&amp;lt;` in XML in the same circumstances you'd need it in HTML -- when you need to represent `&lt;`.

Comment: Not sure if &lt; is the best example, but it is a very real problem with htmlspecialchars.  It's fundamentally intended for HTML escaping, not XML.  PHP provides better tools for the job than htmlspecialchars, and those should be used instead.

Comment: I have an issue trying to insert strings with pound signs in the data (£), and htmlentities does not work, I do not think this is the correct answer, unless for some reason I'm doing something wrong. Using htmlentities, the string it returns is not accepted by DOMDocument::loadXML function. any other suggestions?

Comment: Does the built-in Soap Client also cleanse strings like DOMDocument?

Comment: `or using a library for building XML documents, such as DOMDocument` 
it doesnt help

Answer (score 115):

Since PHP 5.4 you can use:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_XML1);
```

You should specify the encoding, such as:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8');
```

---

### Update

Note that the above will only convert:

- `&` to `&amp;`
- `<` to `&lt;`
- `>` to `&gt;`

---

If you want to escape text for use in an attribute enclosed in double quotes:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_XML1 | ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

will convert `"` to `&quot;` in addition to `&`, `<` and `>`.

---

And if your attributes are enclosed in single quotes:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_XML1 | ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

will convert `'` to `&apos;` in addition to `&`, `<`, `>` and `"`.

(Of course you can use this even outside of attributes).

---

See [the manual entry for htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8') worked good for me, actually i do this all of them just for safety

Comment: In cases where you are formatting a string for SimpleXML that needs to be XML validated this seems to be the cleanest working solution.  I am dealing with lots of special characters being used and this solved my issues.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` does not escape `\xB` (vertical tab) for instance, which is [invalid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14192135/2683737).

Answer (score 12):

1) You can wrap your text as CDATA like this:

```
<mytag>
    <![CDATA[Your text goes here. Btw: 5<6 and 6>5]]>
</mytag>
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

2) As already someone said: Escape those chars. E.g. like so:

```
5&lt;6 and 6&gt;5
```

Comment: *oops* I overlooked that CDATA was already mentioned in the previous answer

Comment: You made it very clear what I needed to do, so I appreciate that, regardless of whether it was already mentioned.  I ended up using your solution for a quick fix, but the best practice would probably be to use XMLWriter has Artefacto mentioned, so I'm giving the best answer to him.

Comment: +1 for CDATA (but be careful, XML parsers can be set up to leave CDATA blocks out of the parsed tree)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$str = htmlentities($str,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

So, after filtering your data using `htmlentities()` function, you can use the data in XML tag like:

```
<mytag>$str</mytag>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: After filtering your data using htmlentities function, you can use the data in XML tag like <mytag>$str</mytag>

Answer (score 6):

If at all possible, its always a good idea to create your XML using the XML classes rather than string manipulation - one of the benefits being that the classes will automatically escape characters as needed.

Answer (score 6):

Adding this in case it helps someone.

As I am working with Japanese characters, encoding has also been set appropriately. However, from time to time, I find that `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` are not sufficient.

Some user inputs contain special characters that are not stripped by the above functions. In those cases I have to do this:

```
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1f]/','',htmlspecialchars($string))
```

This will also remove certain `xml-unsafe` control characters like `Null character` or `EOT`. You can use this [table](http://defindit.com/ascii.html) to determine which characters you wish to omit.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the way Golang does quote escaping for XML (and a few extras like newline escaping, and escaping some other characters), so I have ported its XML escape function to PHP below

```
function isInCharacterRange(int $r): bool {
    return $r == 0x09 ||
            $r == 0x0A ||
            $r == 0x0D ||
            $r >= 0x20 && $r <= 0xDF77 ||
            $r >= 0xE000 && $r <= 0xFFFD ||
            $r >= 0x10000 && $r <= 0x10FFFF;
}

function xml(string $s, bool $escapeNewline = true): string {
    $w = '';

    $Last = 0;
    $l = strlen($s);
    $i = 0;

    while ($i < $l) {
        $r = mb_substr(substr($s, $i), 0, 1);
        $Width = strlen($r);
        $i += $Width;
        switch ($r) {
            case '"':
                $esc = '&#34;';
                break;
            case "'":
                $esc = '&#39;';
                break;
            case '&':
                $esc = '&amp;';
                break;
            case '<':
                $esc = '&lt;';
                break;
            case '>':
                $esc = '&gt;';
                break;
            case "\t":
                $esc = '&#x9;';
                break;
            case "\n":
                if (!$escapeNewline) {
                    continue 2;
                }
                $esc = '&#xA;';
                break;
            case "\r":
                $esc = '&#xD;';
                break;
            default:
                if (!isInCharacterRange(mb_ord($r)) || (mb_ord($r) === 0xFFFD && $Width === 1)) {
                    $esc = "\u{FFFD}";
                    break;
                }

                continue 2;
        }
        $w .= substr($s, $Last, $i - $Last - $Width) . $esc;
        $Last = $i;
    }
    $w .= substr($s, $Last);
    return $w;
}
```

Note you'll need at least PHP7.2 because of the `mb_ord` usage, or you'll have to swap it out for another polyfill, but these functions are working great for us!

For anyone curious, here is the relevant Go source https://golang.org/src/encoding/xml/xml.go?s=44219:44263#L1887