# Render XML output in HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, html-table

I have XML output written in PHP which looks like below

```
<Twitch_XML>
  <twitch>
    <Bird id="1">
      <Species>Willow ptarmigan</Species>
      <Age>2</Age>
      <Sex>Male</Sex>
      <Location>London</Location>
      <Image>
        http://www.kidzone.ws/images-changed/birds/willow_ptarmigan.jpg
      </Image>
      <User>Chamith</User>
    </Bird>
    <Bird id="5">
      <Species>Grey partridge</Species>
      <Age>2</Age>
      <Sex>Male</Sex>
      <Location>London</Location>
      <Image>
        https://www.rspb.org.uk/Images/greypartridge_tcm9-17615.jpg?width=530&crop=(196,364,1006,820)
      </Image>
      <User>Raveen</User>
    </Bird>
  </twitch>
</Twitch_XML>
```

I want to put this output inside a HTML table. Please note that I'm not using external XML document. I retrieve data from MySQL and print directly to XML using `savexml()` method

To render data inside the HTML table I tried to use the following code:

```
$twitcdm->saveXML();
foreach($twitcdm->Twitch_XML->twitch as $xmv){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$xmv->id}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$xmv->Species}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$xmv->Age}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$xmv->Sex}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$xmv->Location}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$xmv->Image}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$xmv->User}</td>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

But when I run this it gives me an error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
C:\Winginx\home\localhost\public_html\chamith\twitch_id.php on line 67
```

This is the whole PHP code that I used to generate XML output

```
    $id = $_GET["twitch_id"];
    $command = "SELECT  id,species,age,sex,location,image,username FROM chamith_twitch.twitch  WHERE id = $id";
    $dboutput = $mysqlconnection->query($command);
    $mysqlconnection->close();
    $no_of_raws  = $dboutput->num_rows;


    if ($no_of_raws > 0) {
        while ($line = $dboutput->fetch_array()) {
            $lines[] = $line;
        }

        $dboutput->close();
        $twitcdm = new DOMDocument();
        // $twitcdm->formatOutput = true;
        $twitcdm->appendChild($twitcdm->createElement('Twitch_XML'));
        $fetch_xml = $twitcdm->documentElement;     
        $xmldoc = $twitcdm->createElement('twitch');


        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $dbpkey  = $line['id'];

            $twitch = $twitcdm->createElement('Bird');
            $twitch->setAttribute("id", $line['id']);
            $Species = $twitcdm->createElement('Species');
            $age = $twitcdm->createElement('Age');
            $Sex  = $twitcdm->createElement('Sex');
            $address = $twitcdm->createElement('Location');
            $twitch_photo = $twitcdm->createElement('Image');
            $record_owner = $twitcdm->createElement('User');

            $header    = $twitcdm->createTextNode($line['species']);
            $Species->appendChild($header);
            $twitch->appendChild($Species);        
            $header    = $twitcdm->createTextNode($line['age']);
            $age->appendChild($header);
            $twitch->appendChild($age);
            $header = $twitcdm->createTextNode($line['sex']);
            $Sex->appendChild($header);
            $twitch->appendChild($Sex);          
            $header    = $twitcdm->createTextNode($line['location']);
            $address->appendChild($header);
            $twitch->appendChild($address); 
            $header  = $twitcdm->createTextNode($line['image']);
            $twitch_photo->appendChild($header);
            $twitch->appendChild($twitch_photo);
            $header   = $twitcdm->createTextNode($line['username']);
            $record_owner->appendChild($header);
            $twitch->appendChild($record_owner);
            $xmldoc->appendChild($twitch);   
        }
        $fetch_xml->appendChild($xmldoc);
        // header('Content-type:  text/xml');
        $twitcdm->saveXML();
```

I want to populate these XML data inside table, how can I fix this ?

Comment: someone please help me with this ??

Comment: why not generate the table from the DB directly without XML in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues here:

**1. invalid XML**
see http://www.xmlvalidation.com and test your XML. Turns out that this line

```
https://www.rspb.org.uk/Images/greypartridge_tcm9-17615.jpg?width=530&crop=(196,364,1006,820)
```

is causing problems because it contains **invalid characters**. See [Invalid Characters in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730133/invalid-characters-in-xml) on this site. You may want to check out [How do you make strings XML"safe"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426090/how-do-you-make-strings-xmlsafe) for solutions.

**2. wrong referencing of the XML object**

```
foreach ($twitcdm->Twitch_XML->twitch as $xmv) {
    // etc.
}
```

- `$twitcdm` represents the root node `<Twitch_XML>`
- you forgot the `<Bird>` node in the above XML path

**Do instead:**

```
foreach ($twitcdm->twitch->Bird as $xmv) {
    echo $xmv->Image . PHP_EOL;
    // etc.
}
```

See a working example using `CDATA` to include invalid characters in the XML and a correct XML path in the `foreach`: https://eval.in/321334
*(using SimpleXML instead of DOM, no big deal though)*

**Notes:**

Since you create the XML yourself, you can include handling of invalid characters there. Moreover, I'd advise to use consistent uppercase/lowercase in naming nodes, e.g. `<twitch>` but `<Bird>`.