# error on line 1 at column 158: AttValue: " or ' expected

Tags: php, xml, rss, jwplayer

Please help me find out where I mistake. I'm trying to create xml from php file to make a playlist for JWPlayer 6, however I can't figure out this error from XML:

> error on line 1 at column 158: AttValue: " or ' expected

```
// xml
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
$xml    =   "<rss version='2.0' xmlns:jwplayer='http://rss.jwpcdn.com/'><channel><item>";
$xml    .=  "<title>".$play[0][0]."</title><description></description><jwplayer:image></jwplayer:image><jwplayer:source file=".$provider.$code."/></item>";
$xml    .=  "</channel></rss>";
echo $xml;
exit();
```

Comment: Nobody can help me out? :(

Answer (score 0):

The part where you create `jwplayer:resource` element is not correct :

```
<jwplayer:source file=".$provider.$code."/>
```

You missed the quotes around `file` attribute value :

```
<jwplayer:source file='".$provider.$code."'/>
```

Comment: If I do that, I get this error:
**error on line 1 at column 157: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values**

Comment: @NoHope212 If `$provider` and/or `$code` may contains `<`, then you'll need [escape that character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents).

Comment: Please read the following and try to fix it by yourself first : [How do you make strings XML“safe”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426090/how-do-you-make-strings-xmlsafe). Post a new question if you still can't apply solution suggested there to your case.